# DoesNotExists Error with django and celery

Tags: django, django-models, celery

Following is a basic celery code

```
 @app.task
 def t_select(booking_id, seat_id, user_id):
     with transaction.atomic():
         booking = Booking.objects.get(id=booking_id)
         booking.seats.add(Seat.objects.get(pk=seat_id))
         return booking.save()
```

Which gives the following error:

```
[2018-04-01 02:25:55,893: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: functors.booker.t_select[cec7f2ca-bca0-4f3e-9865-102f3528ce3a]  
[2018-04-01 02:25:55,894: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task functors.booker.t_select[e3a69d6b-1fc9-44cb-96ce-bfe18a1c96a9] raised unexpected: DoesNotExist('Booking matching query does not exist.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/harshil/Courses/SE/movie_recommender/functors/booker.py", line 9, in t_select
    try:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 403, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
booking_system.models.DoesNotExist: Booking matching query does not exist.
```

On printing Booking.object.all(), I get 3 objects, which is what i use to call the above function. Hence there shouldn't be `DoesNotExist` error. Could anyone help me figure out the problem?

EDIT: It only occurs while testing the code

Comment: what did you get by printing `booking_id`

Comment: if i put print(booking_id) inside t_select function, then the line number of the errors remain the same and it doesn't print the value. If i print it before starting the function, it prints 1. I made a record just before calling it.

Comment: Show the code where you called `t_select` function.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Tuyv4snH. booker.select is a proxy for t_select

Comment: Where do you creating `Booking` objects in your test module ?

Comment: booker.start_booking

Comment: It's possible that your celery worker is using a different database than the test database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a real celery process? Or are your celery settings set to eager (as in, synchronous with your tests)? If you're using a real celery process, then it's likely that your objects are created in the test database, while celery's django instance is trying to access the real database.

Try setting your settings to eager and see if it still acts the same.